# Send message to UWP socket app from windows form socket app

Tags: c#, tcp, uwp

I have built a UWP socket server and UWP client which works. I am trying to pass a string from windows form to a UWP server. Is there a way to send the string the same way that the UWP client sends the string? below shows how the UWP sends the string and the way windows form sends the string.

```
  //send from win form which results in out of memory error
  private void buttonSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string msg = richTextTxMessage.Text;
            //// New code to send strings from windows form to uwp server
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(m_clientSocket);
            System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new 
            System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(msg);
            streamWriter.Flush();

            //Use the following code to send bytes

            //byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            //if (m_clientSocket != null)
            //{
            //    m_clientSocket.Send(byData);
            //}

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

//the UWP send button that works

```
 private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _socket.Send(txtMessage.Text);
    }
```

//the UWP client send is:

```
 public async void Send(string message)
    {
        //Envia o tamanho da string
        _writer.WriteUInt32(_writer.MeasureString(message));
        //Envia a string em si
        _writer.WriteString(message);

        try
        {
            //Faz o Envio da mensagem
            await _writer.StoreAsync();
            //Limpa para o proximo envio de mensagem
            await _writer.FlushAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (OnError != null)
                OnError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This almost works doesnt error out the server but data received is never executed on UWP  server

```
public async void Send(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(richTextTxMessage.Text);
            //Send the message
            await writer.WriteAsync(message);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Exception thrown: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in ServerSocket.winmd

Comment: I figured it out you can use some of the UWP code in a windows app. After reading this article https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/ I could use the UWP data writer exactly like in the code that worked its a little confusing in the article but it did work I simply added the reference to Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract problem solved. I posted it here for others who may have a similar problem.

Comment: This nuget package is easier to understand https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop